# CSS - Images wont appear on same line as Select box

Tags: html, css

Check out my problem with this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/85BN8/3/

Both the `select` and the `img` tag are set to have the same heights.

And yet this is not making them appear "on same line".

It is as if the select box prefer being aligned 'bottomly' vertically...

Does anyone have a tip?

Thanks in advance!

Edit: Thanks all. I accepted the answer that was first and worked.
All others got +1 for their answer... Awesome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed it. Just add `float: left` to both of them.

http://jsfiddle.net/85BN8/12/

Answer (score 2):

```
#testdiv img {
    border:1px solid black;
    width:25px;
    vertical-align:top;
    height:25px;
}
```

Try specifying vertical-align.

Comment: Didn't know you could do that one. Nice. :)

Comment: Nice... I have been going on and on about trying to mess with the styles for the select box, because it's visually not in place. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

To `#testdiv select`, add `vertical-align: top`.

[***Live Demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/85BN8/11/)

Answer (score 1):

Add a float to your image. See below:

```
    #testdiv img {
        border:1px solid black;
        width:25px;
        height:25px;
        float: left;
    }
```